# Não consigo executar o comando "php artisan storage:link"

Tags: php, laravel

Existem alguma maneira de executar esse comando em um servido como o hostgator?
no meu pc eu consigo somente com direitos administrativos, mas na conexão com o hostgator não é possivel aparece o seguinte erro

```
   ErrorException  : symlink(): No such file or directory

  at /home4/dan18048/public_html/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:252
    248|      */
    249|     public function link($target, $link)
    250|     {
    251|         if (! windows_os()) {
  > 252|             return symlink($target, $link);
    253|         }
    254|
    255|         $mode = $this->isDirectory($target) ? 'J' : 'H';
    256|

  Exception trace:

  1   symlink("/home4/dan18048/public_html/blog/storage/app/public","/home4/dan18048/public_html/blog/public/storage")
      /home4/dan18048/public_html/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:252
  2   Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::link("/home4/dan18048/public_html/blog/storage/app/public", "/home4/dan18048/public_html/blog/public/storage")
      /home4/dan18048/public_html/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/StorageLinkCommand.php:35
```

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que acessar o terminal e criar o symlink manualmente

Comment: Acesso ao terminal eu tenho, mas não sei como criar o symlink manualmente. tentei algumas coisas aqui pesquisando mas não sei como dizer os diretórios corretamente tbm

Comment: Algo assim `ln -s /diretorio/storage /diretorio/public/storage`

Comment: Valeu, consegui :D